# Script / Macro to keep last "0" after decimal (w/o forcing the decimals for entire column)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I keep a list of tasks:

```
177
178
179
```

Sometimes there are subtasks

```
177.1
177.2
177.3
```

Those times I get to 177.10 excel removes the last "0". I don't want to make the entire column have decimals. Seeing the following would be terrible.

```
177.00
178.00
```

Aside from manually going into each individual xxx.10 cell and forcibly changing the formatting is there anything that can be done?

I'm looking for a conditional script or macro.

Comment: So you want the task numbers to be `177.8, 177.9, 177.10, 177.11`? If yes and if you type them in manually, just add a `'` in front of them or force the formatting of the cell to be "Text"

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Yeah. I'm lazy. :)  Actually the ' is a great solution. I can type it in and not have to go to the alignment dialog box.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - make that an answer. I'll vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the task numbers to be

```
177.8
177.9
177.10
177.11
```

Then, if you type them in manually, just add a ' in front of them.